# Add birthday field on user account

Tags: users, datetime

I want to enable my users to add their birth days in their profile. The users should select the date either from a calendar or insert them in three different fields of day,month, and year manually...The image should make it clear:

[image]

Comment: I thought of using the Birthdays module but its not yet stable for Drupal7.

Comment: have tried the date module. http://drupal.org/project/date it has a date picker widget when you add a date.

Comment: @Mohammed Shameem thanks..will go ahead with Dates

Comment: date module does give me the option for my above shown use case...any other suggestions

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd just get the [Date](http://drupal.org/project/date) module and add a date field to the profile called something like `field_user_birthday`.

> This package contains both a flexible date/time field type Date field
>   and a Date API that other modules can use.

Comment: No problem - if this is the answer yo're looking for don't forget to accept it to keep the question queues clean.